# Converting ARW pictures taken with a Sony A6000 to PNG or TIFF with ImageMagick

Tags: software, sony-alpha

I took a few ARW pictures with a [Sony A6000](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I8BICB2) (a.k.a. Sony ILCE-6000). I would like to convert them to PNG or TIFF with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). I tried:

```
convert DSC00288.ARW test.tiff
```

and

```
convert DSC00288.ARW test.png
```

but the output image is not good (colors are faded):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am I misusing ImageMagick or does the latter simply fail to properly support ARW conversion?

---

With `-verbose`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick (by default) uses ufraw-batch to convert RAW files, including ARW. I'd make sure you have the latest version of [ufraw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net) installed. The Sony ILCE-6000 (aka α6000) is on the supported list, so it *should* be okay. If you add the `-verbose` flag to `convert`, it should show you exactly how it's calling out. My guess is that if you update the ufraw it's using, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks. ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate seems to use [dcraw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dcraw) instead. I tried to replace the dcraw by the binary version on the [official website](https://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/), as the a6000 (= ILCE-6000) is said to be supported, but ImageMagick didn't like it :/ I'll try again tomorrow, but if any idea is welcome! I also opened the .ARW file directly in ufraw (latest version) but colors are also distorted.

Comment: Since ImageMagic just converts the raw file to PAM as a preliminary step and the  consumes that file. So why not just call dcraw directly (specify TIFF output) yourself? Then you can figure out the conversion options more directly.